# GUI wifi manager for Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, gui

Is there a library that gives GUI to setup the wifi with Raspberry Pi ?.

This is what I want to do :). Once the Raspberry Pi is connected to a power source, I want it to automatically start GUI wizard to walk the user through setting up wifi (if they haven't already)

Something like [WiFiManager for ESP8266](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager)

My ideal workflow would be,

- User plugs the Raspberry Pi to power (for the first time)
- User browse to an ip (E.g 192.168.0.4) from their phone / computer
- Wifi wizard loads
- Follow the wifi wizard and it sets up the wifi in Raspberry Pi

I did search , but couldn't find anything related, with GUI.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is wrong with the normal GUI button to setup WiFi?

Comment: Hi @Milliways, thanks, I want someone who has just a basic knowledge to get it working. (as all these smart home products in market) , WiFiManager manager does exactly what I want (havent tested it yet), walking through user with few simple step. But I cannot find any equivalent for Pi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [raspberry](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=204182#p1267370) forum, the equivalent of wifimanager for RPi is the [comitup](https://davesteele.github.io/comitup/), it's still in development, but works like a [wifimanager](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager).

Comment: thanks @Jhoney, that seems to be the one what I was looking for, I'll have a look :)